# Forgot google account?

Tags: google

Ok so my girlfriend changed her google account after she bought a new phone but she still had the old Google account before she changed it on the new phone cuz that's what she set up on it when she bought it but now she can't remember the new one cuz we had to factory reset the phone.  So the question is can we back the phone up to the old Google account on it or not?   Or is there nothing at all we can do unles she remembers the password?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to recover your girlfriend's account with this link - [Google Account Recovery](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiOg6OFxfTNAhUIpY8KHfByDr0QFggeMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Frecovery%2F&usg=AFQjCNFVI7rdxuQjzu-2DudhY__g3mPf8w&sig2=dpXNvwzYZjSUTBsL6xulMQ)

Hope this helps and she manages to retrieve her account =)